# Smarter string replace based on a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`string1` + `\t\t\t\t\t\t\t` + `string2`

`string1` can be anything and `string2` can be one of the following: Display, Search, Fee.  For the escaped characters, sometimes I get 10, sometimes I get 5, sometimes I get some amount N...  I am only expecting one `\t` character between `string1` and `string2`.

What I have so far:

```
string newLine0 = line.Replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDisplay", "\tDisplay");
string newline1 = newLine0.Replace("\t\tFee", "\tFee");
string newLine2 = newline1.Replace("\t\tSearch", "\tSearch");
string newLine3 = newLine2.Replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDisplay", "\tDisplay");
string newLine4 = newLine3.Replace("\t\tDisplay", "\tDisplay");
```

Is there a better way to do this with cleaner code and less variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could simply replace instances of more than one `\t` with a single `\t`:

```
string newLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t{2,}", "\t");
```

If you only want to remove extra tabs if one of the words `Display`, `Fee` or `Search` follows, use

```
string newLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t{2,}(?=Display|Fee|Search)", "\t");
```

Comment: Having more than one tabs is possible in places where two columns are NULL, side-by-side.  But it's *not* possible if the tabs are preceding the words Display, Search, or Fee.  How do I account for that?  @"\t{2,}Display"?

Comment: You can use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in that case, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If N tabs precede a word, make N be 1:

```
string newLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"\b(\t+)(\t\w)\2\b", "$+");
```

`\b` - starting from a word boundary

`(\t+)` - match one or more tabs (first grouping)

`(\t\w)` - followed by just one tab and a word (second grouping)

`\2` - match the second captured group

`$+` - substitute the whole match (`/\t*\w/`) with only the second matched group (`/\t\w`).